# Pending Navigations still processing when navigating from page constructor or OnNavigated method in MAUI

Tags: maui, maui-windows

I am using MAUI with .NET 7 and I want to implement login flow. Basic case I have is to have only 2 pages: Dashboard and Login. Third page is Loading page that has no layout, just serves as a routing page. Flow is:

Loading page is the first one in the AppShell definition so it is loaded first

In the constructor of the Loading page or in the OnNavigated() overriden method (behaves the same in both cases) I reroute to Login or Dashboard page depending if the user has token saved. In this simple code Exception is thrown with the description "Pending Navigations still processing"

Code works on Android emulator but not in the Windows app. Windows app starts to work when Task.Delay(1) is set before caling navigation

This is the shell markup:

```xml
<ShellContent

    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"

    FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"        

    Title="Loading"

    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate layout:LoadingPage}"

    Route="{x:Static clientApp:Routes.LoadingPage}" />

<ShellContent

    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"

    FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"

    Title="Login"

    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate account:LoginPage}"

    Route="{x:Static clientApp:Routes.LoginPage}" />

<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">

    <ShellContent

    Title="Dashboard"

    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate dashboard:DashboardPage}"

    Route="{x:Static clientApp:Routes.DashboardPage}" />

</FlyoutItem>
```

This is the simple code that doesn't work on windows app  but works on Android emulator:

```cs
public partial class LoadingPage : ContentPage

{

    public LoadingPage()

    {

        InitializeComponent();        

        BindingContext = viewModel;

    }

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)

    {

        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);

        //await Task.Delay(1); Will work if I uncomment this

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{Routes.LoginPage}");        

    }

}
```

I expected that this simple code will work. I tried to add artificial delay and that succeded but I don't see that as a clean solution. I also searched the web for help, found similar cases but  not this one.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code you provided and I found no issue on my side by using the following code.

Here is the code in Appshell.xml:

```
<ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
   
<ShellContent

    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"

    FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"        

    Title="Loading"

    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoadingPage}"

    Route="LoadingPage" />

<ShellContent

    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"

    FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"

    Title="Login"

    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"

    Route="LoginPage" />
```

Here is the code in LoadingPage.xaml.cs:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)

    {

        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//LoginPage");

    }
```

Comment: As I can see, you have  the  main page as  the  first one  in the AppShell, I don't know how  you managed to reproduce the issue if the Main page is the one which will load first. and redirect line is in the LoadingPage.  I created a simplest project I will upload to GitHub. I is simple MAUI app generated by Visual Studio and only change is added login page and  navigation from main page to login page in the event: OnNavigatedTo().  Still doesn't work in Windows.

Comment: When I navigated to the Loadingpage it will run the the `OnNavigatedTo` method at once. It worked well.

Comment: I've the same issue, and also for me it works fine with Task.Delay().